Laravel Reverb and Flutter Chat App not working
I am Trying to make a ChatApp using Flutter's dart_pusher_channels and Laravel Reverb. AS given in Laravel docs I have setup Sanctum authentication. Then created an Event in Laravel:
class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public $message;
    public function __construct(Messages $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        $channels = [];

        $participants = ChatParticipants::where('chat_id', $this->message->chat_id)->pluck('user_id');

        foreach ($participants as $userId) {
            $channels[] = new PrivateChannel('chat.' . $userId);
        }
        return $channels;
    }
    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'message.sent';
    }
}


Then I have updated the routes/channels.php:
Broadcast::channel('chat.{id}', function (User $user, $id) {
    return $user->id === $id;
});

I have also tried with ShouldBroadcastNow...Next I have made changes in bootstrap/app.php
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        // channels: __DIR__.'/../routes/channels.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withBroadcasting(
        channels: __DIR__.'/../routes/channels.php',
        attributes: ['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']],
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

then after message is created in the db I have tried to broadcast the message :
broadcast(new MessageSent($message));
Then I ran my backend server on port 8000,also my reverb server using 'php artisan reverb:start --debug' on port 8080 and also 'php artisan queue:list'.Now in flutter I have used this snippet to connect to server :
 Future<void> dartconnect() async {
    try {
      final auth = Provider.of<AuthState>(context, listen: false);

      const hostOptions = PusherChannelsOptions.fromHost(
        scheme: 'ws',
        host: '*.*.*.*',
        key: 'reverb_key',
        shouldSupplyMetadataQueries: true,
        metadata: PusherChannelsOptionsMetadata.byDefault(),
        port: 8080,
      );

      final client = PusherChannelsClient.websocket(
          options: hostOptions,
          connectionErrorHandler: (exception, trace, refresh) {
            refresh();
          });

      final private = client.privateChannel(
        'chat.${auth.user!.id}',
        authorizationDelegate:
            EndpointAuthorizableChannelTokenAuthorizationDelegate
                .forPrivateChannel(
          authorizationEndpoint: Uri.parse('$domain/api/broadcasting/auth'),
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ${auth.loginToken}',
          },
        ),
      );

      StreamSubscription<ChannelReadEvent> privateSubscription =
          private.bind('message.sent').listen((event) {
        print('Private event received:${event.data} ');
      });

      client.onConnectionEstablished.listen((s) {
        print('Connection established');
        private.subscribe();
      });

      await client.connect();
  
    } catch (e) {
      
    }
  }


I am not able to get response in my frontend. I have tried other drivers like pusher as well and used other flutter packages like Web socket channel, pusher channels fixed, etc. But none seems to work

create a

pusher_connect.dart

    import 'dart:async';
    
    import 'package:dart_pusher_channels/dart_pusher_channels.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    
    import '../controllers/auth/auth_controller.dart';

    final RxString socketId = ''.obs;

    Future<void> connect(String id) async {
      const hostOptions = PusherChannelsOptions.fromHost(
        scheme: 'ws',
        host: '192.168.122.1',
        key: 'reverb app key',
        shouldSupplyMetadataQueries: true,
        metadata: PusherChannelsOptionsMetadata.byDefault(),
        port: 6001,
      );
    
      final client = PusherChannelsClient.websocket(
          options: hostOptions,
          connectionErrorHandler: (exception, trace, refresh) {
            refresh();
          });
    
      final channel = client.publicChannel(
        'public-user.5.wallet',
      );
    
      final chatsChannel = client.privateChannel(
        'private-chats.$id',
        authorizationDelegate:
            EndpointAuthorizableChannelTokenAuthorizationDelegate.forPrivateChannel(
          authorizationEndpoint: Uri.parse('your-domain/api/broadcasting/auth'),
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          },
        ),
      );
    
      StreamSubscription<ChannelReadEvent> channelSubscription =
          channel.bind('App\\Events\\MessageCreated').listen((event) {
        print('Event received: ${event.data}');
      });
    
      StreamSubscription<ChannelReadEvent> privateSubscription =
          chatsChannel.bind('App\\Events\\MessageCreated').listen((event) {
        print('Private event received: ${event.data}');
      });
    
      client.onConnectionEstablished.listen((s) {
        print('Connection established');
        channel.subscribe();
        chatsChannel.subscribe(); 
socketId.value = chatsChannel.connectionDelegate.socketId!;
      });
    
      await client.connect();
    }

in your php event file, It is best to hook the broadcast event to a parent model id of the ChatParticipants,in this case Chat model.
public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('chat.'. $this->message->chat_id),
        ];
    }

routes/channels.php:
    Broadcast::channel('chat.{id}', function (User $user, $id) {
        $chat = Chat::find($id);
return Gate::authorize('view', $chat);
    });

make sure to add 'X-Socket-ID': socketId.value to your headers when submiting data to your server.
headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        'X-Socket-ID': socketId.value
      };

      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
      request.headers.addAll(headers);


Can you give us complete example as for me public channel is working but not authenticating for private & presence channel

it is not authenticating because in your controller file (php), you are not initializing the 'auth:sanctum' middleware.

in CommentsController file
class CommentsController extends Controller
            {
                public function __construct()
                {
                    $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
                }
            public function store(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
                {
                    $this->validate($request, [
                        'message' => 'required|string|max:255',
                    ]);
        $hostel = Hostel::findHostel($request->hostelName,withoutEagerLoads:true);
                    /** @var Comment $comment */
                    $comment = $request->user()->comments()->create([
                        'message' => $request->message,
                        'commentable_type' => Hostel::class,
                        'commentable_id' => $hostel->id,
                    ]);
    if ($request->hasFile('images')){
                foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
                    try {
                        $comment->addMedia($image)->toMediaCollection('images');
                    } catch (FileDoesNotExist|FileIsTooBig $e) {
                        report($e);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            // Broadcast the event
            broadcast(new CommentCreatedEvent($comment))->toOthers();
    
            return response()->json(new CommentResource($comment->fresh([
                'media',
    //            'commentReply'=>['client.media','media','votes'],
                'client.media',
                'votes'])),201);
        }

// in CommentCreatedEvent file
class CommentCreatedEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public Comment $comment;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return PrivateChannel
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [new PrivateChannel('comments.'. $this->comment->commentable_id)];
    }


       /**
        * Get the data to broadcast.
        *
        * @return array
        */
       public function broadcastWith(): array
       {
           $resource = CommentResource::make($this->comment->load([
                   'media',
                    'commentReply'=>['client.media','media','votes'],
                    'client.media',
                    'votes'
               ]), true);
           return [
               'comment' =>  $resource,
           ];
       }
}

in channels.php file
    Broadcast::channel('comments.{commentId}', function(\App\Models\User $user,string $hostelName){
    return \App\Models\Accommodation\Hostel\Hostel::findHostel($hostelName,withoutEagerLoads:true)->exists();
});

in hostel_socket.dart file
class HostelSocket{
  String hostelName;
  HostelSocket({required this.hostelName});
  
  final RxString socketId = ''.obs;
  late final PusherChannelsClient client;
  late final StreamSubscription<ChannelReadEvent> commentSubscription;
  
  late final PrivateChannel commentChannel;

  Future<void> connectToHostelChannel() async {
    const hostOptions = PusherChannelsOptions.fromHost(
    scheme: 'ws',
    host: '192.168.122.1',
    key: 'reverb app key',
    shouldSupplyMetadataQueries: true,
    metadata: PusherChannelsOptionsMetadata.byDefault(),
    port: 6001,
  );
    client = PusherChannelsClient.websocket(
        options: hostOptions,
        connectionErrorHandler: (exception, trace, refresh) {
          refresh();
        });

    
    

    commentChannel = client.privateChannel(
      'private-comments.$hostelName',
      authorizationDelegate:
      EndpointAuthorizableChannelTokenAuthorizationDelegate.forPrivateChannel(
        authorizationEndpoint: Uri.parse('$broadcastingAuth?hostelName=$hostelName'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${Get.find<AuthController>().box.read('token')}',
        },
      ),
    );

   

    commentSubscription = commentChannel.bind('App\\Events\\CommentCreatedEvent').listen((event) {
      final eventData = jsonDecode(event.data);
      final newComment = Comment.fromJson(eventData['comment']); // Assuming the event data contains a 'comment' key

      
      if (Get.isRegistered<HostelController>()) {
        var commentList = Get.find<HostelController>().commentList;

        // Check if the comment already exists in the list
        if (!commentList.value.data.any((existingComment) => existingComment.id == newComment.id)) {
          // Add the new comment to the list
          commentList.value.data.add(newComment);
        } else {
          // Update the existing comment in the list
          final index = commentList.value.data.indexWhere((existingComment) => existingComment.id == newComment.id);
          if (index != -1) {
            commentList.value.data[index] = newComment;
          }
        }
        // Update the UI
        Get.find<HostelController>().newMessageCount++;
        Get.find<HostelController>().update();
      }
    });

    client.onConnectionEstablished.listen((_) {
     
      commentChannel.subscribe();
      socketId.value = commentChannel.connectionDelegate.socketId!;
      // socketId.value = reservationsChannel.connectionDelegate.socketId!;
    });

    await client.connect();
  }


  void disconnect(){
    
    commentSubscription.cancel();
    
    commentChannel.unsubscribe();
    
    client.disconnect();
  }
}

in hostelController.dart file
    class HostelController extends GetxController{

final box = GetStorage();
  var commentList = CommentsCollectionModel(
          data: <Comment>[].obs,
          links: Links(first: '', last: '', prev: null, next: ''),
          meta: Meta(currentPage: 0, from: 0, lastPage: 0, links: [], path: '', perPage: 0, to: 0, total: 0))
      .obs;

  var _socketId = ''.obs;

  get socketId => _socketId.value;

  set setSocketId(String newState) {
    _socketId.value = newState;
  }
      @override
      void onInit() {
        super.onInit();
        hostelName = Get.arguments['hostelName'];
        fetchHostel().then((_){
          if(hostel != null){
            hostelSocket = HostelSocket(hostelName: hostel!.id);
            hostelSocket!.connectToHostelChannel();
           setSocketId = hostelSocket!.socketId.value;
          }
        });
      }
 

     @override
      void onClose() {
        if(hostel != null){
          hostelSocket!.disconnect();
        }
        super.onClose();
      }
Future<void> sendCommentToServer(String content) async {
    try {
      setCommentLoading = true;
      var hostelName = Get.find<RootController>().selectedHostel?.id;
      final url = Uri.parse('$appBaseUrl$hostelName/comments');
      String? token = box.read("hotelierToken");
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        'X-Socket-ID': socketId
      };
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      request.fields['message'] = content;

      var mediaIndex = 0;
      for (var medium in Get.find<CommentInputController>().selectedMedia) {
        final file = await medium.getFile();
        request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'images[$mediaIndex]', // Use an array field name for multiple files
          file.path,
        ));
        mediaIndex++;
      }
      var response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        // Comment successfully sent, add it to the list
        var responseStream = response.stream;
        var responseBody = await responseStream.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

        Comment newComment = Comment.fromJson(json.decode(responseBody));
        addComment(newComment);
      } else {
        // Handle error (e.g., show a snackbar)
        Get.snackbar('Error', 'Failed to send comment');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      // Handle network or other errors
      Get.snackbar('Error', 'Failed to send comment catch');
    } finally {
      setCommentLoading = false;
      Get.find<CommentInputController>().selectedMedia.clear();
      update();
    }
  }


use this package : pusher_client_socket: ^0.0.2+7
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:pusher_client_socket/pusher_client_socket.dart';

class ReverbService {
  late final PusherClient pusherClient;
  // late final Channel channelName;

  final options = const PusherOptions(
    key: 'your reverb app key',
    host: 'localhost', // REVERB_HOST
    wsPort: 8080, // REVERB_PORT
    encrypted: false, // (Note: enable it if you'r using wss connection)
    authOptions:
        PusherAuthOptions('http://localhost/broadcasting/auth', headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer AUTH-TOKEN' // your sanctum auth token
    }),
    autoConnect: false,
  );

  Future<void> initChannel() async {
    pusherClient = PusherClient(options: options);

    pusherClient.onConnectionError((error) {
      print("Connection error - $error");
    });
    pusherClient.onError((error) {
      print("Error - $error");
    });
    pusherClient.onDisconnected((data) {
      print("Disconnected - $data");
    });
  }

  void connect() async {
    pusherClient.connect();
  }
}

in your UI, do this
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pusher_client_socket/pusher_client_socket.dart';
import 'package:reverb_websocket_flutter/pusher_service.dart';
import 'package:reverb_websocket_flutter/reverb_service.dart';

class UpdateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const UpdateScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<UpdateScreen> createState() => _UpdateScreenState();
}

class _UpdateScreenState extends State<UpdateScreen> {
  final pusher = PusherService();
  String sdata = "No data";


  final reverb = ReverbService();
  late Channel channel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    reverb.initChannel();

    reverb.pusherClient.onConnectionEstablished((data) {
      // print("Connection established - socket-id: ${pusherClient.socketId}");
      print("Connection established - data: $data");
      channel = reverb.pusherClient.channel("test-channel");
      channel.subscribe();
      channel.bind("TestEvent", (Map<String, dynamic> e) {
        log(e.toString());
        // var jsonData = jsonDecode(e);
        setState(() {
          sdata = e['message'];
        });
      });
    });

    reverb.connect();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Update Screen')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(sdata),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('Send Message'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This works for me
